# Drools - Rule to check whether an array does not contain object with only certain properties

Tags: arrays, drools, contains

I am trying to write a Drools rule to identify whether an array of items contains an item that the user has selected.

My session looks similar to the following (admittedly this is simplified but the concept is the same):

```
data = {
    items=[
        {
            prop1=1,
            prop2=2,
            prop4=4
        }
    ],
    selectedItem={
        prop1=1,
        prop2=2
        prop3=3
    }
}
```

The data is converted from JSON into HashMaps and ArrayLists - where data is a HashMap, items is an ArrayList of HashMaps and selectedItem is an HashMap.

Basically, I want the rule to fire only when the items array does not contain an Map that resembles selectedItem. By "resembles", I mean that prop1 and prop2 are the same.

Is this possible with Drools?

I have tried:

```
when
    Map( data.items not contains Map( prop1 == data.selectedItem.prop1, prop2 == data.selectedItem.prop2 ) )
then
    // do something
```

But this returns:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
BuildError: Unable to Analyse Expression !( data.items contains Map( prop1 == data.selectedItem.prop1, prop2 == data.selectedItem.prop2 ) ):
java.lang.Class cannot be cast to org.mvel2.util.MethodStub

Comment: Why using `, ` instead of `&&`

Comment: Perhaps you look into the basics of Drools syntax. What constitutes a "pattern". How are patterns combined into rules. What is a constraint. Also, make sure to present Java code that describes your classes. A java.util.Map does  not contain a property `data`.